# Bash: cd using keyword expressions

Tags: bash, cd

Let's take the following directory listing as an example:

```
folder-1-one
folder-2-two
folder-3-three
```

Let's further assume, I want to cd into `folder-1-one`.

I could use tab completions but this becomes tedious if I have plenty of very similar folder names.

Instead I would like to use some sort of keyword expression. In the example case, `1` and `one` is unique to the folder I want to access.

Thus I am looking for something like `cd 1` or `cd one` to quickly change into the desired directory without having to pay attention at what point the `1` or the `one` occur in the file name.

What would be a good solution for that use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [bash aliases](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html) to hardcode the directories you change to freqeuntly:

```
alias one='cd folder-1-one'
alias two='cd folder-2-two'
```

Alternatively you could look into using zsh, which supports fuzzy completion via 'oh-my-zsh'. Similar facilities for bash exist (although I can't vouch for them) - such as [this one](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion).

Comment: Very nice. Fuzzy Bash Completions is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use wildcards

```
cd *1*
cd *2*
cd *three
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cd *one
cd *two
```

etc.. but keep in mind that if there is another `dir-one` then you will get ambiguous warning.